# Update with LEFT JOIN pdo php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join

I wanted to UPDATE multiple tables at the same time so I used LEFT JOIN to create a single query for my UPDATE. I tried 2 approach to make the LEFT JOIN but both failed. I don't see where i made the mistake so I am hoping someone might be able to dissect the query properly and point out the error.

I already applied some formatting to the query so that i would look readable than it used to look:

First is:

```
"UPDATE "
.
"table1 AS t1 SET t1.Bid = :id "
.
"LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 SET t2.id = :id ON t1.Bid = t2.id AND t1.status = t2.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 SET t3.Bid = :id ON t1.Bid = t3.Bid AND t1.status = t3.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4 SET t4.id = :id ON t1.Bid = t4.id AND t1.status = t4.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table5 AS t5 SET t5.Bid = :id ON t1.Bid = t5.Bid AND t1.status = t5.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6 SET t6.id = :id ON t1.Bid = t6.id AND t1.status = t6.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table7 AS t7 SET t7.Bid = :id ON t1.Bid = t7.Bid AND t1.status = t7.status "
.
"LEFT JOIN table8 AS t8 SET t8.id = :id ON t1.Bid = t8.id AND t1.status = t8.status "

.
"WHERE t1.Bid = :oldid AND t1.status = :status "
```

Second one is:

```
$stmt = $dbh - > prepare("UPDATE "
    .
    "table1 AS t1 "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.Bid = t2.id AND t1.status = t2.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.Bid = t3.Bid AND t1.status = t3.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t1.Bid = t4.id AND t1.status = t4.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table5 AS t5 ON t1.Bid = t5.Bid AND t1.status = t5.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6 ON t1.Bid = t6.id AND t1.status = t6.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table7 AS t7 ON t1.Bid = t7.Bid AND t1.status = t7.status "
    .
    "LEFT JOIN table8 AS t8 ON t1.Bid = t8.id AND t1.status = t8.status "
    .
    " SET t1.Bid = :id, "
    .
    " SET t2.id = :id, "
    .
    " SET t3.Bid = :id, "
    .
    " SET t4.id = :id, "
    .
    " SET t5.Bid = :id, "
    .
    " SET t6.id = :id, "
    .
    " SET t7.Bid = :id, "
    .
    " SET t8.id = :id "

    .
    "WHERE t1.Bid = :oldid AND t1.status = :status ");
```

***UPDATE***

I am using the first option and i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 SET t2.id = '315-512-613-12' at line 1'

Second one gets:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET t2.id = '315-512-613-123V', SET t3.Bid = '315-512-613-123V', SE' at line 1'

Comment: So what's the problem? Please include expected and actual result of both requests. I believe the Mysql syntax to **update** multiple tables is `UPDATE t1, t2, t3 SET t1.field1=value1, t2.field2=value2 ... WHERE t1.pk=t2.fk ...`

Comment: Check the error returned by MySQL when you execute your query.

Comment: @AlexBlex i expect it to update but i get error..i will check the error and paste it on update..I dont need to use left join is that what you mean?but what if the specific ID does not exist in the table that would mean it will not be updated.that is one reason why i used `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I had it working using this query.`

```
"UPDATE 
    table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN
    table2 AS t2 ON t1.Bid = t2.id AND t1.status = t2.status LEFT JOIN
    table3 AS t3 ON t1.Bid = t3.Bid AND t1.status = t3.status LEFT JOIN
    table4 AS t4 ON t1.Bid = t4.id AND t1.status = t4.status LEFT JOIN
    table5 AS t5 ON t1.Bid = t5.Bid AND t1.status = t5.status LEFT JOIN
    table6 AS t6 ON t1.Bid = t6.id AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN
    table7 AS t7 ON t1.Bid = t7.Bid AND t1.status = t7.status LEFT JOIN
    table7 AS t8 ON t1.Bid = t8.id AND t1.status = t8.status
    SET t1.Bid = :id,
        t2.id = :id,
        t3.Bid = :id,
        t4.id = :id,
        t5.Bid = :id,
        t6.id = :id,
        t7.Bid = :id,
        t8.id = :id
    WHERE t1.Bid = :oldid
    AND t1.status = :status "
```